# How to include/configure lua_ls on lspconfig?

Tags: lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I am trying to include `lua_ls` on my lspconfig but I am getting this error
`` [lspconfig] Cannot access configuration for lua_ls. Ensure this server is listed in `server_configurations.md` or added as a custom server. ``

It will only appear after I add `lua_ls` to `ensured_installed` on `mason-lspconfig`.

I`m using `mason` and `lazy.nvim` for plugin manager.

Here is my mason-lspconfig setup

```lua
{
        "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
                ensure_installed = {
                    "angularls",
                    "bashls",
                    "cssls",
                    "eslint",
                    "gopls",
                    "html",
                    "jsonls",
                    "lua_ls",
                    "rust_analyzer",
                    "svelte",
                    "tailwindcss",
                    "tsserver",
                    "yamlls",
                },
            })
        end,
    },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was my lazy.nvim config, removing the `defaults.version="*"` config of `lazy.nvim` fix the issue, because it was installing the stable version of `lspconfig` that is not compitable with the latest `mason-lspconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was clearing the directory: 
~/.local/share/nvim/

Then reinstalling plugins again.

....I was using vim-plug as a plugin manager with init.vim earlier, before switching to Mason with init.lua.